# FreeBSD and pf - packet filtering based on OpenVPN usernames

Tags: vpn, firewall, openvpn, freebsd, pf

I have an OpenVPN server which authenticates the users using an Active Directory server. I need to limit the bandwidth of each user based on their usernames, and I also want to be able to do some basic packet filtering on OpenVPN users. Users are assigned random IP addresses and I prefer to not change that. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Pf for that.

`ipfw2` would be simpler because with its `dummynet`-subsystem you can enforce equal bandwidth sharing policy for all of IPs in a given IP-network. Check out `ipfw2` pipes and queues.